# child and parent fire two different events when clicked on a child

Tags: jquery, parent, children

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="dropdownedit">
<div class="dropbtn">textxyz</div>
<div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;">
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text1">text1</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text2">text2</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text3">text3</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text4">text4</div>
</div></div>
```

and this jquery events to handle the dropdown view/hide events:

```
 $(document).on('click',".dropdownedit", function (e) {
$(this).children('.dropdown-content').css("display", "block");
     });

   $(document).on('mouseover',".dropdown-content", function (e) {
$(this).css("display", "block");
     });

   $(document).on('mouseout',".dropdown-content", function (e) {
$(this).css("display", "none");
   });
```

Furthermore I have a on-click-event for the class "ocond" that should close the dropdown-content class when a option is clicked in the dropdown menu:

```
$(this).parents('.dropdown-content').css("display", "none");
```

but it is not closing after the click it stays visible. I guess it conflicts with:

```
$(document).on('click',".dropdownedit", function (e) {
$(this).children('.dropdown-content').css("display", "block");
     });
```

due to the fact that dropdownedit is a parent of the "ocond"-class div and is fired as well when someone clicks on the "ocond" class.

I try to add to prevent the parent event when clicked on the child event:

```
$(".dropdownedit .ocond").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

});

but no success.
How could I solve this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the commands are conflicting with each other. If you come down one level for the `click` event which is designed to leave the menu open and add a class to override the `hover` show/hide functionality then you will get the results you want without a conflict.

Attaching the `.click()` event to the `.dropbtn` and using `.nextAll()` to find the `.dropdown-content` will avoid the current conflict.

**N.B.** I've used `.nextAll()` which finds all the siblings that match a particular selector, I've followed this with `.first()` so that the code only affects the first instance of this. It means it is less likely to interfere with other code.

**I would also strongly advise using `.closest()` (which will find the first occurrence of a selector immediately upstream) rather than `.parents()` that will match any.**

```js
$(".dropbtn").click( function() { 
  $(this).nextAll(".dropdown-content").first().show();
});

$(".dropdownedit").mouseleave( function() { 
  $(this).find(".dropdown-content").hide();
});

$(".ocond").click( function() { 
  $(this).closest('.dropdown-content').hide(); 
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdownedit">
  <div class="dropbtn">textxyz</div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text1">text1</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text2">text2</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text3">text3</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text4">text4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! thank you very much. The click event to open it should be there. I do not want the hover event to open the dropdown. So it should open by a click and go away when leaving it or when clicking one of the ocond class options. what should I change to make it work this way?

Answer (score 1):

I got it! ... just in case someone is interested:

I just added e.stopPropagation(); after the child event (in this case after all the ocond click event action) to prevent the parent from firing the event.